# RecyclerView deletes old views when scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll

I created a `RecyclerView` with data from TMDB Api. I've added an `OnScrollListener` and and inside it I make a new call to Retrofit to get the next page. The `Recycler` shows the new page but the deletes the values from the old page.

For example: I'm on page 2, then I scroll down and the `Recycler` updated the UI with page 3, after that when I try to scroll up, the recycler doesn't load page 2

ApiService.kt

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface TopRatedApiService {
    @GET("movie/top_rated")
    suspend fun getTopRatedMovies(
        @Query("api_key") api:String = BuildConfig.API_KEY,
        @Query("page")page:Int = 1,
    ): MoviesPage
}

object TopRatedApi {
    val retrofitService: TopRatedApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(TopRatedApiService::class.java) }
}
```

HomeFragemnt

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private lateinit var moviesAdapter: MoviesAdapter
    private lateinit var moviesRecycler: RecyclerView
    private var  page: Int = 1

    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        moviesRecycler = binding.topRatedRecycler
        moviesRecycler.addItemDecoration(
            DividerItemDecoration(
                context,
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
            )
        )
        moviesAdapter = MoviesAdapter()
        moviesRecycler.addOnScrollListener(object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                if(!binding.topRatedRecycler.canScrollVertically(10)) {
                    page++
                    binding.viewModel!!.getTopRatedMovieImage(page)
                }
            }
        })
        moviesRecycler.adapter = moviesAdapter
        
        return binding.root
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

HomeViewModel

```
class HomeViewModel(): ViewModel() {

    private val _status = MutableLiveData<MovieModelStatus>()
    val status: LiveData<MovieModelStatus> = _status

    private val _moviesPage = MutableLiveData<MoviesPage>()
    private val moviesPage: LiveData<MoviesPage> = _moviesPage
    private val _movies = MutableLiveData<List<MoviesModel>>()
    val movies: LiveData<List<MoviesModel>> = _movies
    init {
        getTopRatedMovieImage(1)
    }

    fun getTopRatedMovieImage(page: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _status.value = MovieModelStatus.LOADING
            try {
                _moviesPage.value = TopRatedApi.retrofitService.getTopRatedMovies(page = page)
                _movies.value = moviesPage.value?.results
                _status.value = MovieModelStatus.DONE
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _status.value = MovieModelStatus.ERROR
                _movies.value = listOf()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How should I change the code so that I can keep the old pages making an effect of Endless Scrolling, instead of just changing the page

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview